# How to access child navigator and its properties in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using 'Navigator' component to manage different scenes in my react-native app.

Like we can access parent navigators properties from child navigator (say, MyChildNavigator) using  'parentNavigator' property as following :

```
MyChildNavigator.parentNavigator.getCurrentRoutes();
```

How we can access child navigator and its properties or methods like getCurrentRoutes from parent navigator?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example. I hope it will help you.

In my index.android.js file :

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
 var myVar='aVar';
 return (
  <Navigator
    initialRoute={{id: 'page_splash_screen', name: 'Index', myVar:myVar}}
    renderScene={(route, navigator) => {return this.renderScene(route, navigator)}}
    configureScene={(route) => {
      if (route.sceneConfig) {
        return route.sceneConfig;
      }
      return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
    }}  />
  );
}
renderScene(route, navigator) {
 switch (route.id) {
  case "page_splash_screen":
    return (
      <SplashPage
        navigator={navigator} />
    );
  ...
```

and in my SplashPage :

```
class SplachPage extends Component {
 render() {
   var myVar=this.props.myVar;
  ...
 }
}
```

You can pass your function like myVar in my example